# Custom minor ticks in ggplots2

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I´m trying to add *custom minor ticks* to the y-axis of some graphs and I can´t find out how to do it.

Considering the min and max value of each variable, if the difference between two consecutive values of the y-axis is 1, don´t draw anything. If the differences es >2, draw a minor tick (mt) each (this is: e.g. 32, mt, 34, mt, 36.. or, e.g., 30, mt, mt, mt, mt, 35).

I have written the following function

```
# Definir las marcas menores para el eje y
minor_breaks <- function(data) {
   min_val <- min(data)
   max_val <- max(data)
   breaks <- seq(min_val, max_val, by = 1)
   if (length(breaks) > 2) {
      breaks <- breaks[seq(1, length(breaks), by = 2)]
   }
   return(breaks)
}
```

A reproducible example of my data frame

```
stackoverflow <- structure(list(fecha = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 
1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
2018, 2019, 2020, 2021), `Trachinus draco` = c(26, 25, 25, 24, 
26, 26, 27, 28, 28, 27, 27, 26, 25, 27, 26, 26, 26, 26, 27, 29, 
27, 26, 26, 27, 25, 26, 27, 27, 27, 26, 27, 28), `Trachurus trachurus` = c(32, 
35, 34, 31, 20, 32, 31, 33, 32, 31, 31, 30, 33, 31, 29, 29, 31, 
30, 26, 25, 31, 29, 14, 20, 25, 25, 26, 28, 23, 22, 25, 32), 
    `Chelidonichthys lucerna` = c(44, 41, 38, 39, 53, 64, 39, 
    46, 61, 47, 46, 37, 37, 39, 39, 37, 44, 52, 45, 40, 68, 44, 
    38, 42, 49, 41, 46, 47, 57, 49, 63, 61), `Trisopterus luscus` = c(34, 
    29, 27, 35, 27, 28, 30, 29, 27, 22, 28, 28, 28, 29, 30, 28, 
    30, 30, 27, 33, 28, 29, 27, 27, 32, 16, 29, 30, 31, 27, 29, 
    30), `Trisopterus minutus` = c(22, 12, 18, 20, 20, 18, 19, 
    22, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 20, 17, 20, 21, 22, 19, 11, 18, 22, 
    22, 21, 21, 19, 19, 21, 22, 19, 22, 23), `Zeus faber` = c(44, 
    54, 54, 41, 51, 45, 50, 33, 42, 50, 50, 50, 49, 53, 53, 53, 
    51, 53, 47, 47, 46, 41, 33, 46, 48, 47, 43, 44, 54, 48, 47, 
    48), `Buglossidium luteum` = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 
    12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 12, 12, 13, 12, 
    12, 13, 13, 12, 12, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11), `Lesueurigobius friesii` = c(7, 
    7, 7, 8, 7, 8, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
    7, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 6), `Serranus cabrilla` = c(21, 
    20, 20, 22, 23, 16, 17, 24, 21, 20, 22, 23, 22, 23, 25, 24, 
    23, 22, 25, 23, 22, 22, 21, 21, 22, 24, 21, 22, 22, 22, 23, 
    22)), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = "data.frame")
```

And here it is the code I´m using to try to get the figures. The **scale_y_continuos** doesn´t work as expected

```
spp <- colnames(stackoverflow[, -1])

# Crear gráficas
for (i in 1:length(spp)) {
   
   p <- ggplot(stackoverflow, aes(x = fecha, y = stackoverflow[, i + 1])) + #evitamos con +1 el año
      geom_point(shape = 23, fill = "darkgreen", color = "black", size = 1.4) +
      geom_line(color = "grey11", linetype = "dashed") +
      geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = color, show.legend = TRUE) +
      theme_bw() +
      labs(title = spp[i], 
           x = "Año",
           y = "P95 (cm)",
           face = "bold") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "italic", hjust = 0.5)) + 
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1990, 2021, by = 1),
                         labels = c(1990, rep("", 4), 1995, rep("", 4), 2000,
                                    rep("", 4), 2005, rep("", 4), 2010, 
                                    rep("", 4), 2015, rep("", 4), 2020,
                                    rep("", 1)))
   p <- p + scale_y_continuous(minor_breaks = minor_breaks())
     print(p)
}
```

Any help will be more than welcome.

Thanks. Regards

**Update**

@Allan Cameron, I hope this makes my question clearer.

This graph is correct: when y-axis values are consecutive, no minor ticks

[image]

This is the graph I get with my code (no minor ticks between major ticks)
[image]

Desired graph (minor ticks between two major ticks)
[image]

Please, note that major ticks are whole numbers. I have rounded values to zero to avoid to work with decimals numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It may be best to store the output of your current loop as a list rather than printing each iteration. This gives you the freedom to print or manipulate each plot individually. The recommended way to pass different columns to `aes` is to use the `.data` pronoun rather than a subset of the original data frame.

That aside, your `minor_breaks` function doesn't work here because it should output a sequence of numeric values based on the `data` argument, which you are not passing. The result of passing the appropriate values looks like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

plots <- lapply(colnames(stackoverflow[, -1]), function(sp) {
  
  ggplot(stackoverflow, aes(x = fecha, y = .data[[sp]])) +
      geom_point(shape = 23, fill = "darkgreen", color = "black", size = 1.4) +
      geom_line(color = "grey11", linetype = "dashed") +
      geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = 'black', 
                  show.legend = TRUE) +
      theme_bw() +
      labs(title = sp, x = "Año", y = "P95 (cm)", face = "bold") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "italic", hjust = 0.5)) + 
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1990, 2021, by = 1),
                         labels = c(1990, rep("", 4), 1995, rep("", 4), 2000,
                                    rep("", 4), 2005, rep("", 4), 2010, 
                                    rep("", 4), 2015, rep("", 4), 2020,
                                    rep("", 1))) + 
      scale_y_continuous(minor_breaks = minor_breaks(stackoverflow[[sp]]))
})

wrap_plots(plots, ncol = 3, nrow = 3)
```

[image]

However, I don't think your function does what you expect it to do. If we look at the help file for `scale_y_continuous`, we will see that `minor_breaks` should be one of:

> - NULL for no minor breaks
> - waiver() for the default breaks (one minor break between each major break)
> - A numeric vector of positions
> - A function that given the limits returns a vector of minor breaks. Also accepts rlang lambda function notation. When the function has two arguments, it will be given the limits and major breaks.

Currently your method relies on producing a numeric version of positions, but it would be better to use the last method here, a function which takes the limits and major breaks as arguments and outputs the correct values based on them. That, we we get the minor ticks you have described in your question:

```r
minor_breaks <- function(limits, major_breaks) {
  delta <- mean(diff(major_breaks))
  if(delta <= 1) return(major_breaks) else seq(min(limits), max(limits), 1)
}

plots <- lapply(colnames(stackoverflow[, -1]), function(sp) {
  
  ggplot(stackoverflow, aes(x = fecha, y = .data[[sp]])) +
      geom_point(shape = 23, fill = "darkgreen", color = "black", size = 1.4) +
      geom_line(color = "grey11", linetype = "dashed") +
      geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = 'black', 
                  show.legend = TRUE) +
      theme_bw() +
      labs(title = sp, x = "Año", y = "P95 (cm)", face = "bold") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "italic", hjust = 0.5)) + 
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1990, 2021, by = 1),
                         labels = c(1990, rep("", 4), 1995, rep("", 4), 2000,
                                    rep("", 4), 2005, rep("", 4), 2010, 
                                    rep("", 4), 2015, rep("", 4), 2020,
                                    rep("", 1))) + 
      scale_y_continuous(minor_breaks = minor_breaks)
})

wrap_plots(plots, ncol = 3, nrow = 3)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help. It seems that there is no easy solution.
Until I find a way to get what I want (in case there is any), I will set a high number of ticks in the y-axis and then delete the unnecesary ones with an external program sucha as Adobe Illustrator. It´s taking me a long time to find how to do it and right now the external program is the simplest solution right now.

Comment: @JuanCarlos I thought my second version gives the ticks that you wanted? That's how you describe it in your question.

Comment: I have updated my question to shed light on it. I have not explained well what I needed

Comment: @JuanCarlos but the example you showed is exactly what my code produces. Run my code then run `plots[[2]]`

Comment: @ Allan Cameron, when running "wrap_plots(plots, ncol = 3, nrow = 3)" the following error message appears :
`Error in diff(major_breaks) : argument "major_breaks" is missing, with no default`

I have made a slight change in the last line of your function insering a return after the else: `else return(seq(min(limits), max(limits), 1))`. 

The error message is gone but the output is not what your code produces. There are no minor ticks. 
I guess my change solves the error but at the same time changes your result

Comment: @JuanCarlos are you running the latest version of ggplot? My code produces _exactly_ the output shown using the latest versions of R and ggplot

Comment: @ Allan Cameron. I updated to the lastest version of ggplots2 and the problem is gone [link](https://i.postimg.cc/L4NtqzLq/Captura-de-pantalla-1.png)

Comment: @ Allan Cameron. However, there is no minor ticks between two major ticks (see for example, plot 2 and 3 [link] (https://i.postimg.cc/FFZZyt5H/Captura-de-pantalla-2.png)